# Opening GPS settings does not work android

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, latitude-longitude

In my application, I want to open gps settings page, if it is not enabled. To do this when I searched in google, most of them say this code should work;

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

That code opens this page,

[image]

As you see in red box, location settings is ON. But when I get latitude and longitude values they return null. Then I realized that I should click the GPS button in green box to enable GPS settings. But how can I do it programmatically? Which means `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));` does not open actually GPS settings. Is it because of that I use emulator? See below, my GPS actually is not enabled.

[image]

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

your codes only works if you want to location settings page. There is now way to turn on GPS programmatically without asking user. I also had this problem in one of my working and I found a solution with usage of `LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings`. Now I will try to show you how to use it step by step

1. Let say you have a button, and when you clicked this button you want to show location pop-up to enable GPS

   ```
   enableGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           showLocationEnableDialog();
       }
   });
   ```
2. After click this button you should check your `GoogleApiClient` is null or not, and if it is null, you should create an instance at `showLocationEnableDialog()`

   ```
   public void showLocationEnableDialog() {
   if (googleApiClient == null) {
       googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
               .addApi(LocationServices.API)
               .build();
       googleApiClient.connect();

       createLocationRequest();
       PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
               LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
       result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
               setCallback(result);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   }
3. You should define your `createLocationRequest()` and `setCallback()` methods

   ```
   private void createLocationRequest() {
       LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
       locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
       locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000);
       locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
       builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
               .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
       builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
   }

   private void setCallback(LocationSettingsResult result) {
   final Status status = result.getStatus();
   final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
   switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
       case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
           // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
           // requests here.
           break;
       case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
           // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
           // a dialog.
           try {
               // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
               // and check the result in onActivityResult().
               status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), MainActivity.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
           } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
               // Ignore the error.
           }
           break;
       case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
           // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
           // settings so we won't show the dialog.               
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Last step is catch `status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), MainActivity.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);` on our activity's `onActivityResult`. Important point here I used this codes in a fragment, so if you use this codes in an activity, you should replace `getActivity()` with your activity's context. Also `REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS` is equal to `public static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

       switch (requestCode) {
       // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
           case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS: //int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
              switch (resultCode) {
                  case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                  //user enabled GPS, you can do your GPS operation here again
                  break;
                  case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                  // On pop-up user clicked cancel
                  break;
              }
           break;
           }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks this is so useful. Actually I did not want to turn on GPS programmatically. I just wanted to open real GPS settings page(the second image in my post). I mean if I click the GPS button (in green box as you can see in my post,) and turn on GPS manually, program gives me longitude and latitude values. **But how can I open that page programmatically?** The code I used opens another page which does not actually let me get longitude and latitude values.

Comment: I suggest you to test it on a real device, because you are using genymotion, all hardware related functions couldnt work properly. I also use `Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
      startActivity(viewIntent);` and it is working on my app properly.

Comment: Yes now I also think that the issue is because of genymotion. Because so far no one has mentioned this issue as I searched in google. Thanks for all..